# Compiling multiple .metal files into one .metallib

Tags: metal, core-image

I’m currently writing some custom Core Image filters using Metal. For the sake of structure I want to put the different kernels into different `.metal` files with some common includes like you would do with “normal” source files.
However, when the `metallib` tool bundles the different `.air` files created by the Metal compiler into one `.metallib` file, only the kernel functions defined in the first input `.air` file given to `metallib` are visible. Functions from the other `.air` files don’t seem to be included. What’s the reason for this?

I thought (as is the default compilation behavior for Metal files) all Metal sources get compiled into one library that is then used by every custom `CIFilter` class to instantiate their internal `CIKernel` with the function they need.
I now ended up compiling a `.metallib` file for each custom filter with custom build rules and copying all of them them into my framework using a custom build phase. This doesn't seem to be the intended way…

Comment: Would you be able to provide some specifics? Are you saying you have three `.metal` files (A,B,C) with file A containing a global function called `float mod(float x, float y)`, file B contains one kernel called `float4 returnRed`, file C contains one kernel called `float4 returnGreen`, and you wish it all to be one `.metallib`?

Comment: Yes, something like that. I expected to be able to initialize two different `CIKernel`s from this one library—one for the `returnRed` function and one for `returnGreen`. But at least one of them can't find its function in the linked library. Only when both of them where specified in one `.metal` file (and one `.air` file as a result) both functions are present.

Comment: Not sure if I can help. I've been writing kernels for about 3 years now but only picked up with Metal since WWDC (and not 100% yet, hopefully next year). I dropped my demo test last fall to finish up a new app I'm releasing this week. Converting things to Metal is January. :-) But what I did today is update that demo. I now can (a) replace my `GLKView` with an `MTKView`, (b) write both kernels and global functions to a *single* file, and (c) wrap everything into a `CIFilter` and register them....

Comment: I'm calling my kernels using `CIKernel(functionName:fromMetalLibraryData:)`. So if I understand you, I want to split up my `.metal` file but keep `fromMetalLibraryData` for everything. (That's something I'm hoping to do because the transition to metal involves 24 kernels!) Later this week I'll try a few things and comment here on what I find.

Comment: Yeah. All examples from Apple for `fromMetalLibraryData` have all kernels in one `.metal` file—which is really poor separation if you ask me, especially when you have a lot of custom filters. As I said, my approach is working, but it feels quite manual and not like the intended way. Looking forward to your findings!